# Bootstrap Brand Image Showing too large

Tags: css, responsive-design, bootstrap-modal, responsive, responsive-images

Perhaps its my css but my code should show the image in the header at a fixed size. However, it looks like it may be outside of the div. Heres the code.

```
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 top navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="col-md-6">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                    <div class="navbar-header">

                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button> 
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://dev-httpwwwrestechsyscom.pantheonsite.io/sites/all/themes/myWay/logo.png"></a>
    </div></nav></div>

                <div class="col-md-6">  
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <ul class="menu"><li class="first expanded dropdown active"><a href="/" title="" class="dropdown-toggle active" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">About Us <span class="caret"></span></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li class="first leaf active"><a href="/" title="" class="active">Mission Statement</a></li>
    <li class="leaf"><a href="http://dev-httpwwwrestechsyscom.pantheon.io/content/meet-our-team" title="">Meet Our Team</a></li>
    <li class="leaf"><a href="/content/testimonials" title="">Testimonials</a></li>
    <li class="last leaf"><a href="/profiles-football" title="">Sample Athletes Profile</a></li>
    </ul></li>
    <li class="leaf"><a href="/content/eligibility-requirements">Eligibility</a></li>
    <li class="expanded dropdown"><a href="/content/recruiting-info" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">Recruiting <span class="caret"></span></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li class="first leaf"><a href="http://dev-httpwwwrestechsyscom.pantheon.io/content/recruiting-faq" title="">Recruiting FAQ</a></li>
    <li class="last leaf"><a href="http://dev-httpwwwrestechsyscom.pantheon.io/content/recruiting-info" title="">Recruiting Info</a></li>
    </ul></li>
    <li class="last leaf"><a href="/content/elite-membership">Services</a></li>
    </ul><li class="active"></li>

                        </ul>

                    </div>

            </div></div></div>
```

Comment: We can't help you very well without the CSS. Can you add that? Also, please put the code in a snippet or on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so that we don't have to try to recreate your bug before we can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it in this way. Just add desired height to brand image and width will be auto based on height. For example:

```
.navbar-brand img {
   height: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `max-height: 100%` to the `.navbar-brand img` element and it will contain the image inside of `.navbar-brand`. The `height` of `.navbar-brand` is `50px` from bootstrap's css, so to make it bigger than that, change the `height` of `.navbar-brand`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
.navbar-brand img {
  max-height: 100%;
}

/* add/change this if you want to make the navbar brand area bigger */
.navbar-brand {
  height: 100px;
}
</style>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 top navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="col-md-6">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">

          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://dev-httpwwwrestechsyscom.pantheonsite.io/sites/all/themes/myWay/logo.png"></a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <ul class="menu">
            <li class="first expanded dropdown active"><a href="/" title="" class="dropdown-toggle active" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">About Us <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="first leaf active"><a href="/" title="" class="active">Mission Statement</a></li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="http://dev-httpwwwrestechsyscom.pantheon.io/content/meet-our-team" title="">Meet Our Team</a></li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="/content/testimonials" title="">Testimonials</a></li>
                <li class="last leaf"><a href="/profiles-football" title="">Sample Athletes Profile</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="/content/eligibility-requirements">Eligibility</a></li>
            <li class="expanded dropdown"><a href="/content/recruiting-info" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">Recruiting <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="first leaf"><a href="http://dev-httpwwwrestechsyscom.pantheon.io/content/recruiting-faq" title="">Recruiting FAQ</a></li>
                <li class="last leaf"><a href="http://dev-httpwwwrestechsyscom.pantheon.io/content/recruiting-info" title="">Recruiting Info</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="last leaf"><a href="/content/elite-membership">Services</a></li>
          </ul>
          <li class="active"></li>

        </ul>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```